# Why does my array contain all null?

Tags: java, arrays, null

Why does my array contain all null? 
In this area of code

```
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            tokFix[i] = st.nextToken();
            String loo = tokFix[i];
            i++;
            System.out.println(loo);
            System.out.println(tokFix[i]); }
```

When I do

```
System.out.println(loo);
```

it will properly output each string value that is contained in the array

However when I do S

```
System.out.println(tokFix[i]);
```

It will just give me the output of all null values

What is the difference between the two that cause such a thing to happen?

code:

```
    public static String[] parseFixMsg(String fixMsg1,String fixMsg2){
        int i = 0;
        int size = getArraySize(fixMsg1);
        String[] tokFix = new String[size];
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(fixMsg2,(Character.toString((char)01))+"]");
        st.nextToken();
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        tokFix[i] = st.nextToken();
        String loo = tokFix[i];
        i++;
        System.out.println(loo);
        System.out.println(tokFix[i]); }
    return tokFix;  
}


public static int getArraySize(String fixMsg){
    int size = 1;
     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(fixMsg,(Character.toString((char)01))+"]"); 
     st.nextToken();
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            st.nextToken();
            size+=1;
        }
        return size;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the below mentioned line a little above because you increment the variable `i` before printing. Your `toFix[i]` in sysout is always pointing to the next element, which is not yet initialized/assigned:

```
System.out.println(tokFix[i]);
```

Here is the updated code you need

```
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        tokFix[i] = st.nextToken();
        String loo = tokFix[i];
        System.out.println(tokFix[i]);
        i++;
        System.out.println(loo);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
i++;
```

Points to the next element in the sys.out Statement. Do ++i at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an explanation of what is happening, line by line. Let's work through the case when `i = 2`:

```
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    tokFix[i] = st.nextToken(); // Now tokFix[2] is not null
    String loo = tokFix[i]; // Again, so far so good; you're storing tokFix[2] to loo
    i++; // You've incremented i to 3 now! Here's your problem, as seen in the following:
    System.out.println(loo); // Prints out tokFix[2]
    System.out.println(tokFix[i]); // Prints out tokFix[3], which is null
}
```

As others have said, just move your increment to the end of the loop.

```
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    tokFix[i] = st.nextToken();
    String loo = tokFix[i];

    System.out.println(loo);
    System.out.println(tokFix[i]);

    i++; // Now we increment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        tokFix[i] = st.nextToken(); // let's say i=1
        String loo = tokFix[i]; // now loo=  tokFix[1]
        i++;                     // now i=2
        System.out.println(loo);  // print loo value
        System.out.println(tokFix[i]); } // what happen here??? print tokFix[2]. But still not assign a value to that
```

So change this as

```
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        tokFix[i] = st.nextToken();
        String loo = tokFix[i];            
        System.out.println(loo);
        System.out.println(tokFix[i]); 
        i++;
         }
```

Comment: ohhh mc10 has provided same answer